# Filling Livecycle form with Django

Tags: python, django, pdf, livecycle, pisa

I am trying to fill a livecycle created form with form data from django.  Now I think I have the code done correctly but I am having a hard time with the structure of the livecycle form.  Currently I have the ability to populate pdf's created with adobe acrobat but not livecycle.  Is there a certain file structure for livecycle?

Here is the function I call to fill the pdf:

```
def print_rdba(client=None, data=None, investment_form=None):
from django.http import HttpResponse
from clients.models import Client
from dateutil.parser import parse
from settings import URL
from datetime import date
file = ''
print data
fdf = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<xfdf xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/" xml:space="preserve">\n\t<fields>'
fdf += fdf_val_str("primary1_lastname", data.get('lastname'))
fdf += fdf_val_str("primary1_firstname", data.get('firstname'))

if investment_form:
    file = "%s%s" % (URL, investment_form.file.url)

fdf += '''</fields>
    <f href="%s" target="_blank"/>
    </xfdf>''' % file

fdf = fdf.replace('^M', '')

response = HttpResponse(fdf.encode("ISO-8859-1"), mimetype='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=form.xfdf'
return response
```

Here is fdf_val_str:

```
def fdf_val_str(field, val):
val = str(val).replace('&','&amp;')
return '<field name="%s"><value>%s</value></field>\n' % (field, val)
```

My clients edit function in my views.py:

```
@login_required
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_staff or u.rep_set.get().add_clients, login_url='/')
def edit(request, client=None, *args, **kwargs):
from clients.forms import ClientForm
from entity.forms import LocationForm
from investments.models import InvestmentForm
from lib.tools import print_rdba
...
rdba_btn = InvestmentForm.objects.get(id=3)
context = {}
...
if request.POST.has_key('submit-%s' % rdba_btn.code):
            request.user.message_set.create(message='Generating PDF form')
            return print_rdba(client=client, data=form.data, investment_form=rdba_btn)
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you have LiveCycle Forms installed? You could then generate the XML data with DJango and sending it to LiveCycle to render the PDF Form

edit:
And you should notice LiveCycle Designer generates XFA-based forms, which differ from XFDF

Comment: thanks for the response.  I will look for help regarding XFA-based forms

Comment: can you explain how that's done. It doesn't seem like livecycle can automatically do this..

Comment: It will work if you have access to a LiveCycle server. It's another solution, different from LiveCycle Designer.